# location of octave header files

Tags: octave

I am trying to use Octave as an external solver in my C/C++ code.

I read here that one needs to include the octave/oct.h header file. However I am not able to find it on my computer. I have searched everywhere including the octave root directory version 3.0.5.

What should I do?

Comment: I have not used Octave with my C/C++ code but have read about it. This [Octave C++ reference](http://wiki.octave.org/wiki.pl?CPPQuickReference) seems useful.

Answer (score 3):

I found it in my Octave 3.2.2 installation in Windows: C:\Octave\3.2.2_gcc-4.3.0\include\octave-3.2.2\octave.

Are you using another operating system? If so, you may need to install the headers separately. For example, Ubuntu 10.10 has a separate [octave3.2-headers](http://packages.ubuntu.com/maverick/math/octave3.2-headers)  package.

If you are using Windows and your Octave installation does not have the headers, you could try upgrading to 3.2.2 or greater. I got the Windows installer from [Octave-Forge](http://octave.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 2):

For newer versions on Ubuntu, e.g., Octave 3.8.1, the package you must install to get the headers is now called `liboctave-dev`

Answer (score 1):

The include folder of the Octave 4.0.0 installed on Ubuntu can be found at /usr/include/octave-4.0.0/octave.